# Sql filter command only if column value not equal

Tags: mysql, database, sql

I have SQL command it currently shows 
**

1. Name          (Person'e name)                  I only want that starts with AR
2. Country       (ANY COUNTRY)                    But sort them ASC A to Z
3. Normal_State  (this is given in Binary)        Most of them 3 & 4 are equal
4. Current_State (this is also given in Binary)   Only want to if they are not equal

   1 and 2 I got it to work, I need help getting 3 and 4
   for example

**

`SELECT NAME,
       Country,
       NORMAL_STATE,
       CURRENT_STATE
  FROM SOMS_TABLE
 WHERE SOMS_TABLE.NAME LIKE 'AR%'
 ORDER BY SOMS_TABLE.Country ASC`

for example for image below I only want red one's to show up
Thanks
[image: table]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add an AND condition

`AND Normal_State <> Current_State`

Something to this effect:

```
SELECT 
     NAME, 
     Country, 
     NORMAL_STATE, 
     CURRENT_STATE 
FROM SOMS_TABLE 
WHERE SOMS_TABLE.NAME LIKE 'AR%' 
AND NORMAL_STATE <> CURRENT_STATE
ORDER BY SOMS_TABLE.Country ASC
```